# Display local time zone for each location in SELECT

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a table of train rides, using the following sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE train_rides (
    trip_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    origination text NOT NULL,
    destination text NOT NULL,
    departure timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    arrival timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO train_rides (origination, destination, departure, arrival)
VALUES
    ('Chicago', 'New York', '2017-11-13 21:30 CST', '2017-11-14 18:23 EST'),
    ('New York', 'New Orleans', '2017-11-15 14:15 EST', '2017-11-16 19:32 CST'),
    ('New Orleans', 'Los Angeles', '2017-11-17 13:45 CST', '2017-11-18 9:00 PST'),
    ('Los Angeles', 'San Francisco', '2017-11-19 10:10 PST', '2017-11-19 21:24 PST'),
    ('San Francisco', 'Denver', '2017-11-20 9:10 PST', '2017-11-21 18:38 MST'),
    ('Denver', 'Chicago', '2017-11-22 19:10 MST', '2017-11-23 14:50 CST');
```

When  I run the following query against this data:

```
SELECT origination || ' to ' || destination AS segment,
       to_char(departure, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI a.m. TZ') AS departure,
       to_char(arrival, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI a.m. TZ') AS arrival
FROM train_rides;
```

It gives me the following output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| segment                    | departure                 | arrival                   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Chicago to New York        | 2017-11-13 09:30 p.m. CST | 2017-11-14 05:23 p.m. CST |
| New York to New Orleans    | 2017-11-15 01:15 p.m. CST | 2017-11-16 07:32 p.m. CST |
| New Orleans to Los Angeles | 2017-11-17 01:45 p.m. CST | 2017-11-18 11:00 a.m. CST |
| San Francisco to Denver    | 2017-11-20 11:10 a.m. CST | 2017-11-21 07:38 p.m. CST |
| Denver to Chicago          | 2017-11-22 08:10 p.m. CST | 2017-11-23 02:50 p.m. CST |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All of the times are shown in the CST time zone, which is based on the server timezone setting.

**Preferred Output**

I would like to have the output reflect the local timezone for each origination or destination city, like so:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| segment                    | departure                 | arrival                   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Chicago to New York        | 2017-11-13 09:30 p.m. CST | 2017-11-14 06:23 p.m. EST |
| New York to New Orleans    | 2017-11-15 02:15 p.m. EST | 2017-11-16 07:32 p.m. CST |
| New Orleans to Los Angeles | 2017-11-17 01:45 p.m. CST | 2017-11-18 09:00 a.m. PST |
| San Francisco to Denver    | 2017-11-20 09:10 a.m. PST | 2017-11-21 06:38 p.m. MST |
| Denver to Chicago          | 2017-11-22 07:10 p.m. MST | 2017-11-23 02:50 p.m. CST |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I have each time reflect the local time zone? For example, in the first line above, Chicago's departure would display as CST and New York's arrival would display as EST.

One possible solution would be to use the `AT TIME ZONE` qualifier, perhaps using a lookup table like this:

```
----------------------------
| city          | local_tz |
----------------------------
| Chicago       | CST      |
| Denver        | MST      |
| Los Angeles   | PST      |
| New Orleans   | CST      |
| New York      | EST      |
| San Francisco | PST      |
----------------------------
```

I had considered building dynamic queries using a plpgsql code block, but that would be very messy. I do hope that there is an easy, more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learned about the power of SQL subqueries, and the light bulb went off in my head. What follows are two better approaches.

Both of these approaches make use of the following lookup table named `trains_local_timezones`:

```
-----------------------------------------
| city          | timezone    | tz_abbr |
-----------------------------------------
| Chicago       | US/Central  | CST     |
| Denver        | US/Mountain | MST     |
| Los Angeles   | US/Pacific  | PST     |
| New Orleans   | US/Central  | CST     |
| New York      | US/Eastern  | EST     |
| San Francisco | US/Pacific  | PST     |
-----------------------------------------
```

---

### -- Better way (this can scale up as much as needed)

```
-- Add columns to hold local times
ALTER TABLE train_rides
    ADD COLUMN departure_local TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    ADD COLUMN arrival_local TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE;

-- Update departures to reflect local times
UPDATE train_rides
   SET departure_local = departure AT TIME ZONE
   (SELECT timezone from trains_local_timezones tz
     WHERE origination = tz.city);

-- Update arrivals to reflect local times
UPDATE train_rides
   SET arrival_local = arrival AT TIME ZONE
   (SELECT timezone from trains_local_timezones tz
     WHERE destination = tz.city);


SELECT origination || ' to ' || destination AS segment,
       to_char(departure_local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI AM ') ||
       (SELECT tz_abbr from trains_local_timezones tz
           WHERE tr.origination = tz.city) AS local_departure,

       to_char(arrival_local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI AM ') ||
       (SELECT tz_abbr from trains_local_timezones tz
           WHERE tr.destination = tz.city) AS local_arrival
FROM train_rides tr;
```

---

### -- Best way (no need for the extra columns)

```
SELECT origination || ' to ' || destination AS segment,
       to_char(departure AT TIME ZONE
           (SELECT timezone from trains_local_timezones tz
            WHERE origination = tz.city), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI AM ') ||
       (SELECT tz_abbr from trains_local_timezones tz
           WHERE tr.origination = tz.city) AS local_departure,
       to_char(arrival AT TIME ZONE
           (SELECT timezone from trains_local_timezones tz
            WHERE destination = tz.city), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI AM ') ||
       (SELECT tz_abbr from trains_local_timezones tz
           WHERE tr.destination = tz.city) AS local_arrival
FROM train_rides tr;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get the desired results; it is not the most elegant approach, but it does work.

First, i add two additional columns to the train_rides table:

```
-- Add columns to hold local times 
ALTER TABLE train_rides
    ADD COLUMN departure_local TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    ADD COLUMN arrival_local TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE;
```

Then I populate the local departure column using a bunch of code (using the not-so-elegant, brute-force approach):

```
-- Update departures to reflect local times
UPDATE train_rides
    SET departure_local = departure AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central'
    WHERE origination = 'Chicago';
UPDATE train_rides
   SET departure_local = departure AT TIME ZONE 'US/Mountain'
   WHERE origination = 'Denver';
UPDATE train_rides
    SET departure_local = departure AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'
    WHERE origination = 'Los Angeles';
UPDATE train_rides
    SET departure_local = departure AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central'
    WHERE origination = 'New Orleans';
UPDATE train_rides
   SET departure_local = departure AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
   WHERE origination = 'New York';
UPDATE train_rides
   SET departure_local = departure AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'
   WHERE origination = 'San Francisco';
```

Next, I populate the local arrivals in the same way:

```
-- Update arrivals to reflect local times
UPDATE train_rides
    SET arrival_local = arrival AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central'
    WHERE origination = 'Chicago';
UPDATE train_rides
   SET arrival_local = arrival AT TIME ZONE 'US/Mountain'
   WHERE origination = 'Denver';
UPDATE train_rides
    SET arrival_local = arrival AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'
    WHERE origination = 'Los Angeles';
UPDATE train_rides
    SET arrival_local = arrival AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central'
    WHERE origination = 'New Orleans';
UPDATE train_rides
   SET arrival_local = arrival AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
   WHERE origination = 'New York';
UPDATE train_rides
   SET arrival_local = arrival AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'
   WHERE origination = 'San Francisco';
```

Finally, i can use some SQL magic to get the final results:

```
SELECT origination || ' to ' || destination AS segment,
       to_char(departure_local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI a.m. ') ||
       (SELECT local_tz from local_timezones tz
           WHERE tr.origination = tz.city) AS departure,
       to_char(arrival_local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI a.m. ') ||
       (SELECT local_tz from local_timezones tz
           WHERE tr.destination = tz.city) AS arrival
FROM train_rides tr;
```

If there was a way we could dynamically populate the AT TIME ZONE parameter using a lookup, then all of those UPDATE statements could be reduced down to just two. This brute-force approach does not scale up very well, for we have to manually code for each possible city.

Unless, that is, someone knows of a better way.

Comment: What I would do differently is that I'd use `timestamp with time zone` in the database, everything else you do is fine. Then the result of your query is a `timestamp without time zone`, which makes more sense because it indicates that the timestamp is to be understood as being in the time zone dictated by the `origination` column.